# how many reference images used in kinect？

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- I want to construct a depth camera like kinect.
- One referece image is sanped at a distance of 100cm, and servel test images are snapped at different distances. I found if the test image with a distance not similar to 100cm, the disparity can not be calculated correctly. Whether I miss something when I calculate the disparity?
- Is there someone konw how many reference images kinect used?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49682/how-many-reference-images-used-in-kinect%EF%BC%9F/) by [beigua](https://answers.ros.org/users/3717/beigua/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This paper provides a good overview of the Kinect measurement model:

[Accuracy and Resolution of Kinect Depth Data for Indoor Mapping Applications](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/12/2/1437)

In the paper, the authors refer to a parameter Z_0, or the distance to the reference plane. I assume this is what you're asking about. They calibrate for the depth readings, so if you go through the equations, you can find the value of Z_0.

Now in the model the authors describe, they only use a single Z_0. However, it is entirely possible that the Kinect uses multiple and switches dynamically, but that could be hidden from the user.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Kinect does not use reference images of any kind, its more of an active stereo vision approach. There is a known infrared-pattern projected by a laser (this serves as the "right eye") and an camera with an ir-filter as the left eye. [This article](http://mirror2image.wordpress.com/2010/11/30/how-kinect-works-stereo-triangulation/) gives a quick overview. Or with a little marketing in [this document](http://www.primesense.com/en/press-room/resources/file/4-primesense-3d-sensor-data-sheet).

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2